# Disabling DNS in juju deployment

Tags: juju

I have problem with addresses because i don't get IP addres after juju status but "nameNode.localdomain" and I thought maybe if I disable DNS server or service that is responsible to naming my nodes in that way, then I get IP address.

I must disable dnsmasq? How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, can you add some more info to the question? Specifically what provider type you're using (I'm guessing maas, but please don't make us all guess ;).